# TfIDf Vectorizer weights

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, data-analysis, tf-idf

Hi I have a lemmatized text in the format as shown by `lemma`. I want to get TfIdf score for each word this is the function that I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

lemma=["'Ah", 'yes', u'say', 'softly', 'Harry', 
       'Potter', 'Our', 'new', 'celebrity', 'You', 
       'learn', 'subtle', 'science', 'exact', 'art', 
       'potion-making', u'begin', 'He', u'speak', 'barely', 
       'whisper', 'caught', 'every', 'word', 'like', 
       'Professor', 'McGonagall', 'Snape', 'gift', 
       u'keep', 'class', 'silent', 'without', 'effort', 
       'As', 'little', 'foolish', 'wand-waving', 'many', 
       'hardly', 'believe', 'magic', 'I', 'dont', 'expect', 'really', 
       'understand', 'beauty']

def Tfidf_Vectorize(lemmas_name):

    vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',ngram_range=(1,2))
    vect_transform = vect.fit_transform(lemmas_name)    

    # First approach of creating a dataframe of weight & feature names

    vect_score = np.asarray(vect_transform.mean(axis=0)).ravel().tolist()
    vect_array = pd.DataFrame({'term': vect.get_feature_names(), 'weight': vect_score})
    vect_array.sort_values(by='weight',ascending=False,inplace=True)

    # Second approach of getting the feature names

    vect_fn = np.array(vect.get_feature_names())    
    sorted_tfidf_index = vect_transform.max(0).toarray()[0].argsort()

    print('Largest Tfidf:\n{}\n'.format(vect_fn[sorted_tfidf_index[:-11:-1]]))

    return vect_array

tf_dataframe=Tfidf_Vectorize(lemma)
print(tf_dataframe.iloc[:5,:])
```

The output I am getting by:

```
print('Largest Tfidf:\n{}\n'.format(vect_fn[sorted_tfidf_index[:-11:-1]]))
```

is

```
Largest Tfidf: 
[u'yes' u'fools' u'fury' u'gale' u'ghosts' u'gift' u'glory' u'glow' u'good'
 u'granger']
```

The result of `tf_dataframe`

```
       term  weight
261  snape       0.027875
238  say         0.022648
211  potter      0.013937
181  mind        0.010453
123  harry       0.010453
60   dark        0.006969
75   dumbledore  0.006969
311  voice       0.005226
125  head        0.005226
231  ron         0.005226
```

Shouldn't both approaches lead to the same result of top features? I just want to calculate the tfidf scores and get the top 5 features/weight. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what I am looking at here but I have the feeling that you're using `TfidfVectorizer` incorrectly. However, please correct me in case I got the wrong idea of what you're trying.

So.. what you need is a list of documents which you feed to `fit_transform()`. From that you can construct a matrix where, for example, each column represents a document and each row a word. One cell in that matrix is the tf-idf score of the word *i* in document *j*.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

documents = [
    "This is a document.",
    "This is another document with slightly more text.",
    "Whereas this is yet another document with even more text than the other ones.",
    "This document is awesome and also rather long.",
    "The car he drove was red."
]

document_names = ['Doc {:d}'.format(i) for i in range(len(documents))]

def get_tfidf(docs, ngram_range=(1,1), index=None):
    vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', ngram_range=ngram_range)
    tfidf = vect.fit_transform(documents).todense()
    return pd.DataFrame(tfidf, columns=vect.get_feature_names(), index=index).T

print(get_tfidf(documents, ngram_range=(1,2), index=document_names))
```

Which will give you:

```
                    Doc 0     Doc 1     Doc 2     Doc 3     Doc 4
awesome               0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.481270  0.000000
awesome long          0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.481270  0.000000
car                   0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.447214
car drove             0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.447214
document              1.0  0.282814  0.282814  0.271139  0.000000
document awesome      0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.481270  0.000000
document slightly     0.0  0.501992  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
document text         0.0  0.000000  0.501992  0.000000  0.000000
drove                 0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.447214
drove red             0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.447214
long                  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.481270  0.000000
ones                  0.0  0.000000  0.501992  0.000000  0.000000
red                   0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.447214
slightly              0.0  0.501992  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
slightly text         0.0  0.501992  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
text                  0.0  0.405004  0.405004  0.000000  0.000000
text ones             0.0  0.000000  0.501992  0.000000  0.000000
```

---

The two methods you show to get to words and their respective scores calculate the mean over all documents and fetch the max score of each word respectively.

So let's do this and compare the two methods:

```
df = get_tfidf(documents, ngram_range=(1,2), index=index)

print(pd.DataFrame([df.mean(1), df.max(1)], index=['score_mean', 'score_max']).T)
```

We can see that the scores are of course different.

```
                   score_mean  score_max
awesome              0.096254   0.481270
awesome long         0.096254   0.481270
car                  0.089443   0.447214
car drove            0.089443   0.447214
document             0.367353   1.000000
document awesome     0.096254   0.481270
document slightly    0.100398   0.501992
document text        0.100398   0.501992
drove                0.089443   0.447214
drove red            0.089443   0.447214
long                 0.096254   0.481270
ones                 0.100398   0.501992
red                  0.089443   0.447214
slightly             0.100398   0.501992
slightly text        0.100398   0.501992
text                 0.162002   0.405004
text ones            0.100398   0.501992
```

---

**Note:**

You can convince yourself that this does the same as calling min/max on the `TfidfVectorizer`:

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,2))
tfidf = vect.fit_transform(documents)
print(tfidf.max(0))
print(tfidf.mean(0))
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response, my understanding of tfidf was a bit flawed and I assumed that their would be just one document for my string.